# Empty char with String.Split()

Tags: c#, string

I'm working on OBJ files parser, and I need to get information about faces.
In OBJ face sometimes looks like that: `f 1//1 2//1 3//1` or like that: `f 1/1/1 2/4/1 3/2/1`. I'm trying to get these numbers:

```
int[] facePointerValues = Array.ConvertAll(facePointer.Split('/'), int.Parse);
```

If "`f 1/1/1 2/4/1...`" it works, but the problem appears when: "`f 1//1 2//1...`" because of empty char between "/". How to fix that?

Comment: `facePointer.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: I can't believe i can't find a duplicate of this question...

Comment: I doubt that your code worked with `f 1/1/1 2/4/1`, how could you parse `f 1` or `1 2` to int?

Comment: @Tim Because of string[] facePointers = fileLine.Substring(2).Split(' ');

Answer (score 0):

As peeople mentioned in the comments, you can tell `Split()` to ignore empty entries, but then you'll end up with an array size of 2 instead of 3.

Alternatively, you can selectively use 0 for empty values:

```
int[] facePointerValues = Array.ConvertAll(facePointer.Split('/'),
                              s => s.Length < 1 ? 0 : int.Parse(s));
```

This way, you'll still always end up with an array size of 3.